# データベースからのレコードが表示されません。

Tags: java, mysql

javaでアプリケーションを作るためにデータベースの各数値を表示したいです。
エラーは起こっていないのですが、表示されません。

**今までの対処**
表示するためのwhile文に入っていないことが hello2 の出力で分かりました。rs.next() → !rs.next() に変更したところ hello1 が出力され「Illegal operation on empty result set.」のエラーが出ました。そのためrsが空だとわかります。また、データベースとの接続テストができており接続はできているという認識で進めています。
ResultSet がうまく取得できていないと考えたのですがどうにもデータベースからの値が取得できません。どうしたらいいのかわかりません。

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SelectEmployeeSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=JST", "root", "*******");
            //SQL文準備
            final String sql = "select ID,NAME,AGE from employee";
            PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            //SQL実行
            ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
            //取得
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("hello1");
                String id = rs.getString("ID");
                String name = rs.getString("NAME");
                int age = rs.getInt("AGE");
                //出力
                System.out.println("ID:"+id);
                System.out.println("name:"+name);
                System.out.println("age:"+age+"\n");
            }
            System.out.println("hello2");

        }catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: employee テーブルにデータが1件も登録されていないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ひとまず、代わりに `select count(*) from employee` を実行してみるとどうでしょうか。1件結果が返ってくるはずなので、正常にSQL実行できていること、また `employee` テーブルに何件レコードが存在するのか、という2点を確認できるかと思います。

Comment: コミット？保存的なことができてなかったみたいです。ありがとうございました。とても参考になりました。